# mongodb TypeError: client.db.collection is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

when I use "mongodb": "^3.0.5",

```
    const cn = require('./connect');

    function showItems(req, callback) {
      cn.MongoClient.connect(cn.url, (err, database)=> {

        const collection = database.db.collection('items');

        collection.find({}).toArray((err, result)=> {

          callback(result);
        });

        database.close();
      })
    }

    module.exports = showItems;
```

I got,

> /node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:433
>
> throw err
>
> ^
>
> TypeError: database.db.collection is not a function

But,when I use "mongodb": "^2.2.33" , it worked.

```
    const cn = require('./connect');

    function showItems(req, callback) {
      cn.MongoClient.connect(cn.url, (err, db)=> {

        const collection = db.collection('items');

        collection.find({}).toArray((err, result)=> {

          callback(result);
        });

        db.close();
      })
    }

    module.exports = showItems;
```

connect.js

```
    const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/databasename";
    const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    module.exports = {url, MongoClient};
```

Use "mongodb": "^3.0.5" , How to solve this problem ?

Comment: don't know how this works in earlier version, Here is a guide that may help using later/latest version https://github.com/usman154/movieApp

Comment: What does your `./connect` do ? If you want to use `cn.MongoClient.connect` you shoud replace `const cn = require('./connect');` by `const cn = require('mongodb');`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is permission error.so we need to get the database first then try to access the collections. will solve the problem.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const cn = require('./connect');

MongoClient.connect(cn.url, (err, database) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  } else {
    const myDB = database.db('myDatabaseName')
    const collection = myDB.collection('items');
    collection.find({}).toArray((err, result) => {
      callback(result);
    });
    db.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: still this issue

Comment: then uninstall mongo from npm js & reinstall npm package will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
client.collection()
```

instead.

The connect method return the database object.

Comment: TypeError: client.collection is not a function

Comment: Did you check the err value ?